# JSON encoding missing first row from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, fetch

I'm tryinh to encode all rows in table to JSON but it seems to miss the first one.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM NewsStream";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "echo: " . $row["id"]. "  " . $row["title"]. " " . $row["content"]. "<br />";
        echo "JSON: " . json_encode($row). "<br />";
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
echo: 0 title content
JSON: 
echo: 1 abc efg
JSON: {"id":"1","title":"abc","content":"efg","type":"11","author":"12","preview":"13","src":"14","date":"2015-02-20"}
echo: 2 4563 456465
JSON: {"id":"2","title":"4563","content":"456465","type":"54","author":"5463","preview":"6454","src":"456","date":"2015-02-12"}
```

Why the first "JSON: " is missing while echoing results are right?

Comment: Have you tried showing errors in PHP? Also, use `print_r($row)` instead of your first `echo`. `json_last_error()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$return_arr = array();

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM NewsStream");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)) {
$data=array();  
 foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key]=$value;
 }
 $return_arr[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: $return_arr = array();

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM NewsStream");

echo"<pre>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)) {
$data=array(); 
 foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
  $data[$key]=$value;
 }
 $return_arr[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);

Comment: `data_vendor` is not OP's tablename

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM NewsStream";
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows)
```

Comment: you are getting blank result because json_encode is failing to encode the resulted array. Check if you column fields value has single/double quotes in their value. You can try with few selected columns first e.g.  "select field1, field2 from NewsStream"  and then check whether you get encoded data or not